# Android Room inserting a list fails if any object throws a SQL exception

Tags: android, android-room

I have a application that inserts around 20,000 objects that I get from an api and I've found it to be quicker to do batch inserts by creating a list of objects then inserting the list.
The application periodically gets a updated list from the api that I then insert into the database.

I just noticed that if I have a list of... say 20 objects to insert, if even 1 object throws a SQLiteConstraintException(due to unique constraint) NONE of the 20 objects get inserted.

Is there a way to have room insert the other objects that don't throw a SQLiteConstraintException exception? Or should I just individually insert every object?

Here is some example code to demonstrate: [Sample Project Here](https://github.com/rOOb85/RoomInsertIssue)

Entity:

```
@Entity(
    indices = [
        Index(
            value = ["first_name", "last_name"],
            unique = true
        )
    ]
)
data class User(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uid: Int = 0
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Insert
    fun insertUser(vararg users: User)

    @Insert
    fun insertUserList(users: List<User>)
}
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
        )
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
        val userDao = db.userDao()

        // Create 3 users and insert them 1 by 1
        for (i in 0..2) {
            val user = User("first$i", "last$i")
            // First run won't throw any exceptions, but subsequent runs will. Need to catch them.
            try {
                userDao.insertUser(user)
            } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
                Log.e("Room", "onCreate: ", e)
            }
        }

        // There are now 3 User's in the database
        Log.d("Room", "### First 3 User's")
        for (u in userDao.getAll()) {
            Log.d("Room", u.toString())
        }

        // Create 10 users(some of which have the same first and last names)
        // then do a batch insert
        val userList = mutableListOf<User>()
        for (i in 0..9) {
            userList.add(
                User("first$i", "last$i")
            )
        }
        // Need to catch SQLiteConstraintException
        try {
            userDao.insertUserList(userList)
        } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
            Log.e("Room", "onCreate: ", e)
        }

        Log.d("Room", "### Next 10 User's")
        // There are still 3 User's in the database
        for (u in userDao.getAll()) {
            Log.d("Room", u.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy?hl=en#IGNORE

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'm not sure how I missed the IGNORE flag. All my googling only brought up the REPLACE flag. This seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `OnConflictStrategy` property to your `@Insert` annotation to say what you want to have happen when there is a foreign key constraint violation. In your case, `IGNORE` will skip over any failures:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
```

If you care about which ones failed (e.g., logging purposes), I think you can have your function return `List<Int>`. That list should match the length of the list of items you were inserting. The values will either be the `ROWID` of the inserted entry or `-1` to indicate ignored inserts. From the index values of the `-1` entries, you would find out which items themselves failed. I have not tried this, so YMMV.

Comment: This doesn't work for FOREIGN KEY constraint. Is there a way to ignore such errors and just skip bad records?